# Splitting a word into two strings

Tags: r, vector, split

I have a character vector called `x` and I want to separate into two words.

I searched for R functions, but couldn't find the perfect one.

```
x<-c("HANGMAN")
```

Here `x` returns a answers of "HANGMAN"
I want to get back my vector as "HANG MAN" and not "HANGMAN"

The result should be 
HANG MAN

Comment: Hi Muthu, Welcome to Stackoverflow. Could you give us more examples like hangman? you can use gsub("HANG", "HANG ",x)

Comment: @HarshalGajare better with parameter `fixed = TRUE`

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `MAN` with space `MAN` using `gsub`. `fixed = TRUE` is here for exact matching of the string.

```
gsub("MAN", " MAN", x, fixed = TRUE)
```

It is better to replace `MAN` than `HANG` as there are less characters in `MAN`than in many names.